# How to provide window dimension in each react-class

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project with several react-classes and components. In most of these a window resize event and the new window dimension is needed. I don't want a window-event-listner in each component. How can I write a util-class that provides the dimension and is accesible from all other components?

```
updateDimension: function() {
    const height= window.innerHeight;

    this.setState({
        height: height,
    });
    this.forceUpdate();
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option A**

If you are using es6 then this is quite easy:

Define your util function in a separate javascript file.
'../path/to/utils/updateDimension':

```
export function updateDimension(Component) {
    this.setState({
        height: window.innerHeight,
    });
}
```

And then use it in your components like this:

```
import { updateDimension } from '../path/to/utils/updateDimension';

@updateDimension export class YourCompoennt extends React.Component {
   // ...
}
```

The @updateDimension is telling YourComponent to kind of extend the class by that updateDimension function.

**Option B**

Another way would be to make use of Higher Order Components:

Define your util like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export function updateDimension(WrappedComponent) {
  return class Dimensions extends React.Component {
    updateDimension() {
      this.setState({
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
    }
  }
}
```

Then at bottom of each of your components call:

```
export default updateDimension(YourComponent)();
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I add an window-resize listener in Option B?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend coding a [Higher Order Component](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.dk7o7s7ib) for this. It can pass it's children the current window size. eg: viewState="xs"

Additionally you can use a regular JS utility function / class or store the size in [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) but HOC is the most elegant way to do it.